# Plotting text annotation in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm trying to add text annotations to a network when plotting an igraph graph object. I provided a toy example - I can't get any of the text to show up in the (x,y) locations. Can someone modify this so that it works properly?

```
TestAnnoDir <- getwd()

myText <- data.frame(x=seq(2,20,2), y=seq(2,20,2), text= sample(state.name, 10))
fn <- paste(TestAnnoDir, "Test", ".tif",sep="")
tiff(filename = fn, width = 1000, height = 1000)

# toy network example
erdos.renyi = erdos.renyi.game(10, 1/2, directed=FALSE)
plot( erdos.renyi ,
     vertex.size = 3,
     vertex.label = "", 
     vertex.label.color = "black" 
) 

#plot.new()
for(i in 1: nrow(myText)){
  text(x=myText[i,"x"],y=myText[i,"y"], labels=myText[i,"text"])
} 
dev.off()
```

p.s. I'm doing this in RStudio

Comment: Can you ditch the `tiff` stuff here and just show it on the screen?

Comment: The network is plotted freely, so the coordinates are nothing to do with the x and y coordinates in the data frame. Do you want the 10 nodes plotted at the coordinates in the data frame? igraph is trying to lay it out nicely.

Comment: If you want to plot the text at the nodes then `vertex.label=as.character(myText$text)` as an option to plot will do it.

Comment: Hi, sorry @Spacedman but nothing to do with the node text. It doesn't work either if I ditch the tiff stuff (i.e. doesn't work if I write it to file or display in RStudio)

Comment: Yes but there's no point having the TIFF code in there. I can see it's not working on R's graphics window easier than writing a TIFF file and opening an image viewer!

Answer (score 2):

Ah... Looks like the canvas is scaled on -1,1 in both x,y

so this will work:

```
text(0, 0,"0,0")
text(0, 1,"0,1")
text(0, -1,"0,-1")
text(-1, -1,"-1,-1")
text(1, -1,"1,-1")
text(1, 1,"1,1")
text(-1, 1,"-1,1")
```

And looks like 
[image]